# Testing anonymous function equality with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, equality

Is there a way to test anonymous function equality with `jest@20`?

I am trying to pass a test similar to:

```
const foo = i => j => {return i*j}
const bar = () => {baz:foo(2), boz:1}

describe('Test anonymous function equality',()=>{

    it('+++ foo', () => {
        const obj = foo(2)
        expect(obj).toBe(foo(2))
    });

    it('+++ bar', () => {
        const obj = bar()
        expect(obj).toEqual({baz:foo(2), boz:1})
    });    
});
```

which currently yields:

```
  ● >>>Test anonymous function equality › +++ foo

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      [Function anonymous]
    Received:
      [Function anonymous]

    Difference:

    Compared values have no visual difference.

  ● >>>Test anonymous function equality › +++ bar

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      {baz: [Function anonymous], boz:1}
    Received:
      {baz: [Function anonymous], boz:1}

    Difference:

    Compared values have no visual difference.
```

Comment: This a hack rather than an answer. You can try  `expect(''+obj).toEqual(''+foo(2))`. It compares the function string content rather than the function itself.

Comment: @Malice thats not bad, though the second test is closer to my use case, where I have the anon fn assigned to a property in the object I want to compare. Your method could work as the builtin method of choice within `.toEqual` for checking this type of equality

Comment: ...but unfortunate the equality is not entirely accurate, as `''+foo(1) === ''+foo(2)` evaluates to true

Answer (score 111):

In such situation, without rewriting your logic to use named functions, you don't really have another choice other than **declaring the function before the test**, e.g.

```
const foo = i => j => i * j
const foo2 = foo(2)
const bar = () => ({ baz: foo2, boz: 1 })

describe('Test anonymous function equality', () => {
  it('+++ bar', () => {
    const obj = bar()
    expect(obj).toEqual({ baz: foo2, boz: 1 })
  });    
});
```

Alternatively, you can **check whether `obj.bar` is *any* function**, using `expect.any(Function)`:

```
expect(obj).toEqual({ baz: expect.any(Function), boz: 1 })
```

which might actually make more sense depending on the context of the test.

Comment: thx for the answer, your alternative way is enough for my tests!


`expect(result).toEqual({ getFooData: expect.any(Function),  foo: 'some foo string' })`